# Navigate between fragments using Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer with a list view inside it, in order to navigate between my fragments.

Here is the XML file wich contains my navigation drawer and my list view:

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#454545"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the implementation of the listener (when I click on one of the item of the list):

```
        mListViewMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new ImageFragment();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new VideoFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new TextFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new MusicFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            mCurrentMenuSelected = i;

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                ft.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment).commit();
                mListViewMenu.setItemChecked(i, true);
                mListViewMenu.setSelection(i);
                mTitle = mListMenuItems.get(i).getmMenuItem().getmTitle();
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        }
    });
```

... And here is an implementation of one of my fragment (TextFragment in this case):

```
public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

}

My problem: When I click the first time on one of the list's items, my fragment is loaded and displayed, and my navigation drawer is closed (it's ok for the moment). But when I re-open the navigation drawer, I can't click on my list's items any more... The onItemClickListener is not called any more and I can't navigate between others fragments.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The fragments need to be added to the `frame_container` `FrameLayout`. In your code you add the fragments to a layout identified by `R.id.drawer_layout`, which I assume it's the drawer layout itself(if this is the case then you're doing things wrong).